I want to install Ubuntu on my chrome OS device
I want to install Ubuntu on my chrome OS device but every video says TURN ON DEVELOPER MODE but Google says press Ctrl alt shift up switch.
It says to turn on developer mode you need to press ctrl shift alt up arrow or down arrow I did it and it did not work.
I wanted to do it without developer mode because I will be stuck in great risk of attacks. I am using gnome boxes to emulate the thing but that's not what I really wanted to do. I wanted to make Ubuntu my system not Chrome OS.

As written this has noting to do with Ubuntu it is a hardware issue with Chrome OS. Minus the rude statement this is something you need to address with the people that made the machine.

you need to find firmware.

Is this a Chromebook? There are lots of articles on the internet about installing Ubuntu on a Chromebook. There's a very helpful question here on Ask Ubuntu about it.  Bottom line, do some research and come back here with specific questions. I just did it a couple of months ago, so it can be done.  Use the google search term 'chrultrabook'

This question is similar to: How to install Ubuntu on an Intel/AMD Chromebook (e.g. Google Pixelbook 2017)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I wanted to do it without developer mode because I will be stuck in great risk of attacks - to install ubuntu, you have to change the bootloader, and to do that you have to turn on developer mode. Please note that changing the bootloader is like an attack to chromeos. You cannot perform a surgery without knives/lasers.
